# How to send push notification with firebase to ionic app with custom ID?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I am using FCM to send push notifications to Ionic capacitor app and it works perfectly when I am sending notification to all users(I am using this [example](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/guides/push-notifications-firebase)).

Is it possible to provide a list of users(with custom IDs) to firebase to send notifications? I guess than App should send custom ID or property to Firebase and then receive push notification if that ID is in the list.

Comment: sue this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/fcm to get FCM token.  you can send notification to these token specifically.

Comment: thanks for help! what's the difference between token returned from Capacitor and from this library?

Comment: This will be Device specific token you and target to send notification to that specific Device. Store this token to your DB and trigger notification. More in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUr8pw0nO7Y

Comment: I mean as I understood you I should store this token to firebase? How can I send push notifications to multiple devices?

Comment: you can use Firebase Cloud function to send Push Notification to single or Multiple devices.